# Source my bash profile when I su on OS X

Tags: bash, login, bashrc

I'd like to source my `.bash_profile` (or maybe some other file) whenever I switch to superuser. (`.bash_profile` is the login rc on Mac OS X, `.bashrc` is the non-login script, and `.profile` is a login rc that runs for any shell).

Simply, my `.bash_profile` makes using a terminal more convenient for me, and on those occasional times when I have to go super, I feel like I'm trying to play a guitar without thumbs. More than that, `$PS1` and `$PROMPT_COMMAND` get exported to the super user, but functions defined in my `.bash_profile` and used in my `$PROMPT_COMMAND` do not get exported to that lexical environment.

In particular, I source the `git-prompt.sh` script in my `.bash_profile` and use the exported `__git_ps1` command in my `$PROMPT_COMMAND`. Thus, every single prompt line in the superuser shell is preceded by the warning:

> `bash: __git_ps1: command not found.`

Now I technically could modify the system-wide rc in `/etc/profile` in order to achieve the effect. I could look at `$HOME`, and if it's my home, then source `$HOME/.bash_profile`. However, this isn't portable. I would have to modify the `/etc/profile` on every host in which I'm likely to be working. I want to export this behavior to happen on all hosts on which I work.

Can anyone think of a solution that is completely contained in *my own* bash profile?

No warnings about becoming a super user are necessary. I know there's `sudo`, and that it's bad, bad, bad, and I'm morally and intellectually inferior for doing it. :)

Mac OS X's `su` doesn't have the `-c` option, which would have been a pretty good solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright. I have something now. It's not pretty, but it does work. The main trick is that I can cause code to be executed in the super user shell by changing `$PROMPT_COMMAND` in the environment. `$PROMPT_COMMAND` gets executed right away when switching to the new environment, and su preserves bash environment variables.

Thus, here is the solution I'm using:

`alias su="export REAL_HOME=$HOME && export SWITCHING_TO_SU=true && export PROMPT_COMMAND='source $HOME/.bash_profile; $PROMPT_COMMAND' && su"`

Now my `.bash_profile` will be run as soon as I switch to the super user, and it will know two key pieces of information: 1) that it is being run because I am switching to super user, and 2) the location of my real home directory. It can use that information to do anything else it needs to do.  In particular, my .bash_profile will reset `$PROMPT_COMMAND` back to its true value, so that the script gets sourced only when switching to su. At the end of the script, I have

```
if [[ "$SWITCHING_TO_SU" == 'true' ]]; then
    unset SWITCHING_TO_SU
    unset REAL_HOME
fi
```

A similar trick based on aliasing `exit()` could be used, I believe, to do something when switching out of super user.

Comment: I will leave this open in case someone has a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you `su` from your $HOME, you could just do

```
. .bash_profile
```